# Examples of domain models that most people don't understand. Usage: create requirements

Tags: uml, requirements

I'm looking for domain models in which most people don't know or understand very good. I have chosen one domain, health insurance policy, and I'm making requirements (user stories) for that domain. Later I will do some testing with users to investigate domain understanding. This is an perfect example, and I'm looking for more of these: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/health-insurance-policy-domain-diagram-example.html

Since I have limited knowledge with the domains as well, I find the UML-representation and the description very useful. To be able to create some requirements I do need to understand the domain at least some of it.

That's it for now, I hope somebody got some input, I'll be searching the web.

Answer (score 0):

UML does not give a diagram for a task. It has diagrams that can be used for abstract representation of many tasks. Domain modelling is one of them.

The diagram to show how people work with domain model is a use case diagram. You have actors - people - stick men, systems and subsystems (IT systems and organizations) - blocks, use cases - actions - ovals. The more formal behavioral diagrams - State machine and Activity diagrams. But think of them later.

If you want to set a structural model, no one diagram is better than a class one. But it is too formal and if you don't know how to use it, it is difficult to get accustomed to. Start from the next one:

The more common structural model - components diagram. There you show components, their dependencies, their info exchange, what component is an item of the another, container component, what component is a parent (more common case) of another one. Surely, it will cover all your need now. What is better for you, because of its not full formality, it can show not only structure, but behavioral elements, too.  Later, if you will want more abstractness, formality and exactness, try the class diagram.

What you have seen at the link mentioned is not an effective class diagram. It is such only formally. The blood of class diagram are associations, and there are only two of them. It is an example of use of class diagram for showing a hierarchy. But you can show hierarchy on ***ANY*** UML diagram. Why to use the most complex one?

If you are up to the task of class diagram modelling, look here as it can be done:

### My model for User Guide structure:

[image]

Comment: OK, sorry you make a lot of talk here but I don't really understand what you are trying to say. First of all, I'm not creating a UML diagram or components diagram of any kind. I'm looking for one that describe a domain (for example health insurance policy) in a way that I can make user stories from it. From that diagram I am creating user stories for a experiment. So, in case of other types of diagrams they will work fine for me as well, I'm not restricted to them in any way. If I'm completely missing what you are saying then please correct me.

Comment: @cloms You do not use components, but you can use components diagram. The author of the linked page doesn't use classes, but uses class diagram. It is OK. I am only trying to help you to choose the tool for presenting your information.

Comment: @cloms For planning and testing user stories Use Case and State Machine diagrams are the best.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will keep on searching. if there are any tips I'm happy to get them :)

Comment: I can add that I also used this diagram as for creating my user stories regarding health insurance policy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Domain_model.png

Comment: @cloms A plan can have one Deductible in Network and one deductible out of work? Deductible belongs to Plan? What one-direction connections mean? Every Insured person has many DemographicInfo? It seems, I understood: you use the class diagram, but you don't take it strictly. Why not. But better subscribe ends of connection - thus you determine, what is A from the B point of view and vice versa.

Comment: @cloms And beware - for dynamic picture use other diagrams.

Comment: @cloms A composite association cannot be many:many. Being composite means that items exist ONLY in the composite container. So an item can't belong to two containers.

Comment: I don't need to be really strict, because the user stories I'm making are for my experiment which is going to prove a hypothesis considering a treatment I'm giving testers. All I need to do is create these user stories based on a domain that isn't understood by everyone. One user story might be "As a user I would like to sign up for a insurance plan". I agree that a the diagrams are missing information about relations and stuff, but I'll do some assumptions where I'm not 100% sure. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: If you could give some example domain models I would put that as the answer, because that's what I'm looking for! I really need another domain to derive my user stories from.

Comment: Yes, but perhaps a domain that not so many people know how works. The health insurance policy is one domain that at least students at information science do not know very much about, and therefore makes a great example that I can use. Topics considering GUI, development and other IT-relevant subjects is the stuff these students know. Benefits coverage, medicade, job based coverage, family policy, in-network doctors. Specific terms that you could guess what it means, but not really understand it before you read and learn more about it. That's why I choose that. Could you give a brief descrip?

Comment: @cloms They don't know it - it is how ***I*** do the User Guides. I am afraid, it is so easy to understand. What is worse, the classes here are not compliant with LCP and are not compatible with normal programming classes. So, the are not so easy for IT public.